# KeyError if I change constructor variable names

Tags: python, class, keyerror

I'm going crazy trying to perform simple editing while creating a Python class constructor. I can create the simple class and constructor variable but once I try to change the names of the variable I get a `KeyError`.

The class is below:

```
class Collect:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    self.foo = kwargs["foo"]
```

And the script where I instantiate the class and print out its attributes is below:

```
import mapper as m
payload = m.Collect(foo="Hello")
print(payload.foo)
```

Now this works just fine, but if I change "`foo`" to "`bar`" I get a `KeyError` Like below:

```
class Collect:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.bar = kwargs["bar"]
```

and then running:

```
import mapper as m
payload = m.Collect(bar="Hello")
print(payload.bar)
```

will throw the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<stdin>", line 1, in
<module>   File
"/path/to/mapper.py",
line 8, in __init__
    self.bar = kwargs["bar"] KeyError: 'foo'
```

And the `print` function will throw the error below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<stdin>", line 1, in
  <module> AttributeError: 'Collect' object has no attribute 'bar'
```

The weird thing is that if I hit save and then close VSCode and reopen, the new class with bar will work just fine.  And, also even if I don't close VSCode the class will instantiate and the print statement will run just fine when I switch to Debug mode and run it. But when I try to highlight it and run a selection it throws that error.

How can I just test if the code works using the run selection operations and not relying on running in debug mode with breakpoints or having to close and reopen VSCode?

Comment: what's with the `**bar**`

Comment: @JamesLin The asterisks are for highlighting the error.

Comment: `self.bar=kwargs["bar"] KeyError: 'foo'` That error makes no sense.  This sounds like a VS Code internal issue.

Comment: Is this the actual exact code and the actual exact error?  The attempt to use markdown in the code makes me suspicious that the error message has been edited rather than copied and pasted directly.

Comment: This sounds like you edited the file without closing your Python session. You need to restart Python after editing your code.

Comment: Remove all cache files

Comment: Thanks @user2357112supportsMonica.  The VSCode reload extension works well for this.

Answer (score -1):

The solution was to reload my Python session.  The VSCode reload extension makes this easy.